# Photoshop: Loop part of gif

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I know that when making your own gifs in Photoshop you have the ability to have the gif loop forever, but I was wondering if there is any possible way to have only part of the gif loop forever, if that makes sense.

I essentially want it so that way once Part A ends, Part B continuously loops on forever. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The limitation here is the GIF format itself, not Photoshop. The format doesn't allow for such functionality.

There may be other ways to do it however, such as using two gifs, one for each part, and using css/javascript to swap the first GIF after it has played, replacing it with the other on infinite loop. I'm no coder however.  Someone else here might have a solution to that.

Comment: That's what I figured I would have to do but figured it was worth asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically - No

A GIF is just a set of images played in sequence, it does not contain any sort of timeline information.